# Replace text with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to replace certain values in a div using angular. The problem is that the div content is generated by an outside service so I cant just add `ng-model` and be done with it. I've tried the following and some various variations with no luck

```
var o = angular.element(document.querySelector('#maintwo'));
var r = o[0].innerHTML.replace('TWO','REPLACE');
angular.element(document.querySelector('#maintwo')).innerHTML = r;
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mHP2rFumnADyFvKIoe3u)

Comment: missing the [0] from the 3rd line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `angular.element()` from this line, and it will work as you need it  :  `angular.element(document.querySelector('#maintwo')).innerHTML = r;`

Do it , like : `document.querySelector('#maintwo').innerHTML = r;`

Answer (score 1):

if you remove the angular.element() container from the 3rd line it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button ng-click="replaceText()">
  replace
</button>

<div id="maintwo">MAIN TWO</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.replaceText = function() {

     var o = angular.element(document.querySelector('#maintwo'));
     var r = o[0].innerHTML.replace('TWO','REPLACE');
    document.querySelector('#maintwo').innerHTML = r; 

    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```